# Is [fun-stuff] on topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, tags, burninate-request

I just approved two edits removing the tag [fun-stuff](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun-stuff) from the two only posts that currently have it:

[What are the limitations of performing music in space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64524/what-are-the-limitations-of-performing-music-in-space)

[How much force is in a keystroke? (estimated, of course)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/how-much-force-is-in-a-keystroke-estimated-of-course)

For one, it seems pointless to have such a small tag. On top of that, it definitely pushes the limits of on-topic (though a bit of fun never hurt anyone, really). On the other hand, it wasn't really hurting anyone as the question count was minimal.* All in all I'm pretty neutral about this, so I approved the edit. I just thought this should come up in meta before we lose the tag. (Tags with no questions get deleted shortly, as per [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags).)

So, what's it gonna be? Tag burnination? Tag rescue with tens of volunteers turning up all these fun questions that really needed that tag? Or my personal favourite, a long, slow slide of this question down the meta front page, faced with stone-cold utter indifference? (hey, I could even get a tumbleweed outta that...)

<sub>* Yes, I know "minimal" is only one question per tag. Go take this up in math if you feel that strongly about it.</sub>

Comment: I'll save an answer until later so you can earn your tumbleweed, but I say kill the tag because it's a meta-tag anyway that adds no real value to the classifications.

Comment: @tpg2114 nah, tumbleweed's no thing. This is definitely not worth sitting on an answer for a week or even a day. You're good and right that this is an archetypical meta tag, though: burninate, I say!

Comment: That was a mostly tongue-in-cheek comment -- I just didn't have time to answer then!

Comment: Looks like it has no questions now, so it will delete itself within a day. Unless anyone has a good case for keeping this tag, I'm marking it as `[status-completed]`

Answer (score 5):

The tag doesn't add any extra information and is an unnecessary meta-tag. Burn it at the stake!

Answer (score 4):

Fire it from a cannon, launch several cyber-nukes at it, and send the ashen remains into the black hole at the centre of the galaxy...

...in other words, burninate.

Comment: Did you not notice the [meta-tag:status-completed] ? . : ) _+1_, anyway.

Comment: Could not help myself

Comment: And send the rest of the ashes too meta - tag space.